# Deserialize YAML to int[]

Tags: java, yaml

The problem:
How to deserialize data in *.yml file into `int[]`? Have little experience, searched a lot of resources, but do not understand. Serialize data in yml - no problems, but how to do back? For example, an array of integers:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
try 
{
    Yaml.dump(arr, new File("file.yml")); // write to yml
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
{
    Logger.getLogger(Yaml_array.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

And the array writes to *.yml-file:

```
--- !int[]
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

But how read from yml to `int[]` array?
In manual for example this code:

```
Object object = Yaml.load(new File("file.yml"));
```

But what to do with object? How extract data to array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast it:

```
int[] arr = (int[]) Yaml.load(new File("file.yml"));
```